# How to use Cocoapods to update the latest Firebase SDK for iOS

Tags: firebase, xcode14

understand there are new version for Firebase SDK. I used below code but my podfile.lock show the old version.

- Firebase/Auth (8.0.0):

  - Firebase/CoreOnly
  - FirebaseAuth (~> 8.0.0)

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'myApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myApp

  pod 'Firebase/Core' 
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  
   post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
        end
     end
  end

end
```

I use the above Podfile to solve the below issue:

The iOS Simulator deployment target `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99.

I have the following Question:

1. How to update firebase SDK to the latest version?

I run this code with Terminal in Mac with pointing to the Project file:

```
Project $ pod update
```

But my `Podfile.lock` still show the old version

2. Should I change the pod format

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'     to  FirebaseAuth
pod 'Firebase/Database' to  FirebaseDatabase
```

3. How do I check which version firebase SDK installed?
4. I tried to use SPM to install the Firebase but ran into problems and a lot of error messages. Also in SPM,  there is No Firebase/Core or FirebaseCore available.

Thanks